# How do I access a background terminal program started in startup on gnome?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I installed a terminal server program for my Grandson so that when he logs on to Gnome it automatically starts but he needs to access it to edit commands ocasionaly or to shut it down but I can't find access to the Terminal running anywhere. I see it running in system monitor but can't bring it forward. It's a Startup Program .sh file.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't simply moved to another workspace? Try pressing the Windows (Super) key and S to see all of your workspaces.

Comment: That just brings up the power button menu....I'm in Gnome Classic...I went ahead and put it back on the work space for now but would eventually like to put it in startup if he can access it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this to startup, you should be able to find "Startup Applications" in the "System" menu. On Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, the "System" menu is in the top right corner. It's in the same place where you power off the computer.

You can simply click "Add", enter your command and a name, and then click "Save".

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for somebody looking for answer to a similar question, you can see the running background processes started by a terminal program using `ps lx`